# How much voltage do I need to power up a Bitmain Antminer S19 Bitcoin hashing board?

Tags: mining-hardware, asic, antminer

I'm trying to repair a Bitmain Antminer S19 Hashing board. But how much voltage do I need to power this thing up for testing using a benchtop power supply?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Antminer APW12 Power Supply for S19 provides 300 amps at 12-15 volts.

[image: Antminer APW12 power rating label]

Note that just the Stand-By output (12 VSB) alone provides 20 amps.

I had a look to see how much a 300 amp benchtop power supply would cost - it seems to be starting around $5000. That's a lot more expensive than an APW12

Maybe a single board needs much less power but I suspect you need to consult the documentation for the S19.

Answer (score 0):

Using a benchtop power supply. One needs to provide 13.5V and 15 amp to a S19 / S19pro hashboard for testing.

[image]